# DZRPlayerInternalErrorDomain : Invalid Stream

Tags: ios, deezer

I use Deezer SDK in my iOS App and I get very often this error:

> Error Domain=DZRPlayerInternalErrorDomain Code=1 "Invalid Stream" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Invalid Stream}

This error is not listed in the doc [here](https://developers.deezer.com/api/errors)
What is that? How can I fixed it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The error above is not listed in the Deezer API link you've posted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I received from Deezer :

> If you see this error, it means that a secure connection can't be
>   established because your authorization token has expired or wrong. You
>   can check the the token’s expiration date with "[DeezerConnect
>   expirationDate]". When the token has expired, you must re-run the
>   process to generate a new code and retrieve a new token.